# PC Game Pass game crashes at launch with Exception code: 0xc0000005

Tags: windows-11, crash, gaming

## PC Configuration

Lenovo Legion Y740, Model: 81UJ0001US, Intel Core i7-9750H, RTX 2080-MQ, 16GB DDR4 RAM, 1TB PCIe NVMe SSD, Windows 11 Home 22H2 (Build 22621.1635)

GeForce Game Ready Driver 531.79 (02nd May 2023)

## Issue

I installed the game Redfall from PC Game Pass to my D: drive (~200 GB left in drive after installation). Now whenever I try to launch the game in any way (from desktop shortcut OR clicking play button in xbox app OR by going to the installation folder and clicking the app exe), this happens -

- Redfall title splash-screen appears
- At the bottom right of that splash-screen, text appears - "signing in", "syncing data", "launching game".
- And then the splash-screen vanishes and nothing happens. Game has crashed.

## Troubleshooting

1. Made sure that OS and graphics drivers are up-to-date.
2. Tried running the game as Admin
3. Tried running after disabling antivirus (Windows Security) and Firewall.
4. Tried verify and repair option available within Xbox app.
5. Clicked "Repair", and "Reset" option in Windows settings page of MS Store, Xbox app and Redfall app.
6. Fully uninstalled Xbox app, MS Store app and then reinstalled them.
7. Did a clean reboot by disabling all non-MS services in msconfig and startup.

I checked event viewer, and that shows this in the logs -

```
Faulting application name: Redfall.exe, version: 4.26.2.0, time stamp: 0x64431d67
Faulting module name: Redfall.exe, version: 4.26.2.0, time stamp: 0x64431d67
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000011d24cb5
Faulting process id: 0x0x3704
Faulting application start time: 0x0x1D97D8A7C1F3DD7
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\BethesdaSoftworks.Redfall_1.1.253.0_x64__{alphanumeric}\Redfall\Binaries\WinGDK\Redfall.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\BethesdaSoftworks.Redfall_1.1.253.0_x64__{alphanumeric}\Redfall\Binaries\WinGDK\Redfall.exe
Faulting package full name: BethesdaSoftworks.Redfall_1.1.253.0_x64__{alphanumeric}
Faulting package-relative application ID: AppRedfallShipping
```

Quick google search says "Exception code: 0xc0000005" means access violation. Does that mean there's some ownership problem with C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\BethesdaSoftworks.Redfall_1.1.253.0_x64__{alphanumeric}\Redfall\Binaries\WinGDK\Redfall.exe? I went to C:\Program Files\ and took ownership of WindowsApps and all content underneath. The game is still failing crashing.

Please note that C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\BethesdaSoftworks.Redfall_1.1.253.0_x64__{alphanumeric} is a [junction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/hard-links-and-junctions) to D:\WindowsApps\BethesdaSoftworks.Redfall_1.1.253.0_x64__{alphanumeric}.

## Other games with same issue

I believe this is not an issue with the game Redfall, but an issue with the xbox app on Windows. Because I had this same exact issue with multiple games in the past - Atomic Heart, Darq, Plague Tale: Requiem etc.

But it doesn't happen with all games from xbox app. Small / mid-tier AA games install and run fine! So, that's confusing AF.

I did contact xbox support for this, but they apparently don't have official support people employed for this, and there's only "community support".

Any help resolving this?

Comment: Instead of making that location a junction. Uninstall the game and install it at that location on your other drive. Taking ownership of WindowsApps folder most certainly the root of your issue. Best advice restore the original permissions on that folder, if you can’t or won’t do that, I know no other solution to your problem and will be unable to help. No need to tell me your unwillingness to do so as a comment

Comment: The access violation is reference to a memory access violation. While I suspect the problem is the junction point and/or the modified permissions on the folder, suspect the issue caused by something simpler than that. Since you have  GeForce Experience installed use it to set the optimal settings for the game, specifically, disable Ray Tracing. UWP games can’t run as an Administrator, trying to elevate the permissions, does absolutely nothing.

Comment: @Ramhound Changing the ownership of WindowsApps folder was the last thing I did in the troubleshoot sequence. The first 7 steps I wrote down, that folder was owned by the default "TrustedInstaller" during those. So, changing the ownership is certainly not the cause of the issue. Anyway, I did restore the original permission now, and the issue persists.

Comment: Did you also delete the junction point and just move or reinstall the application on your other drive? Windows should create a new WindwsApps folder with the correct permissions on the drive automatically

Comment: @Ramhound The junction wasn't created by me manually. Windows did that itself. In Windows Settings -> Storage -> "Where new content is saved", I have selected "New apps will save to D:". And while downloading the game from xbox app, I selected D: drive. That's why Windows itself created that junction. 

I can't move the game to C: drive anyway. I have only 20 GB free space in C: (200 GB free in D:) and this game is 94 GB.

Comment: @Ramhound Can't set "optimal setting" in GeForce Experience without the game having been launched at least once. Since the game hasn't successfully launched even once, GeForce Experience is saying "Unable to retrieve current settings". And there's no "Optimize" button.

Comment: If the game isn’t listed you’ll have to add it, I certainly in the past, optimized a game I have installed before playing it. I can’t help.